# I have two lists in one big list, how do I take out the individually lists and have them on separate lines

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have an external text file (read_task_doc) that saves the user name and user tasks when reading from the file using this code:

```
user_task = []
for i in read_task_doc:
    task_list = i.strip()
    task_list = i.split(", ")
    if user_login == task_list[0]:
        user_task.append(task_list)
```

It's printing the tasks as:

```
print(user_task)
[['admin', 'Register Users'], ['admin', 'Create user tasks']]
```

How do I extract the two lists from the list and have them on their own line of code as so:

```
['admin', 'Register Users']
['admin', 'Create user tasks']
```

I've tried joining the lists but that just joins it all together not individually.
Zipping is creating lists from each position in their own list.

Comment: Did you try: `print(user_task[0]);print(user_task[1])`?

Comment: Yes thanks and it works but how do I save the variable 'user_task'  in that format

Comment: What is "the variable"? Also, would suggest using `[print(x) for x in user_task]` to print all items in the list instead of manually printing each individually.

Comment: 'user_task' is the variable

Comment: That variable is the list containing the items. Do you want a variable that contains to values? Because that is not possible without a container of sorts.

Comment: @Dani Why do you want `user_task` in that _"format"_?  What do you plan to do with that variable?  How would that _"format"_ help your program later?  BTW, to insure a particular user gets notified of your comment, start your comment with `@userName`.  After you type a few letters of the user name, a popup will show you selections and you can just click on the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
for task in user_task:
    print(task)
```

This will print each task individually as you are expecting, you can also perform other operations on the task variable if you wish.

Also, you might want to read more about `zip` for how and where to use it, [here](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/).

EDIT 1: Usage of `join`, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)